# Count incidences ID from 2 table, where ID is variable between dates

Tags: sql, hive, sas, logic, teradata

I need help with the logic to assemble a query that is able to count the ID of a company, between the same table in difference dates, but the current ID of the company and the old ID change month-by-month, but the register is the same in all times.

In case , the table has 3 key information, DATE, CURRENT ID, OLD ID.

I can locate by crossing 1 reference, using the following query

```
SELECT A.*, COUNT(B.OLD_ID) FROM (
SELECT DATE_, CURRENT_ID , OLD_ID, REGISTER FROM TABLE_A WHERE DATE = X ) AS A
LEFT JOIN
(SELECT DATE_, CURRENT_ID, OLD_ID, REGISTER  FROM TABLE_A WHERE DATE = X-1 ) AS B
ON A.OLD_ID = B.CURRENT_ID AND A.REGISTER  = B.REGISTER
```

In the case, i can count 1 time, but i need to count all the occorrency.
I really don't know how i can do this.

```
SELECT A.*, COUNT(B.OLD_ID) FROM (
SELECT DATE, CURRENT_ID ,
OLD_ID FROM TABLE WHERE DATE = X ) AS A
LEFT JOIN
(SELECT DATE, CURRENT_ID, OLD_ID FROM TABLE WHERE DATE = X-1 ) AS B
ON A.OLD_ID = B.CURRENT_ID AND A.REGISTER  = B.REGISTER
```

Data example:

| DATE | CURRENT_ID | OLD_ID | REGISTER |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 202201 | 123012 | 123321 | 'xpt0' |
| 202202 | 123987 | 123012 | 'xpt0' |
| 202203 | 987321 | 123987 | 'xpt0' |
| 202203 | 789322 | null | 'xpt0' |
| 202203 | 976533 | 987321 | 'wyzx' |

Comment: Connecting by CURRENT ID and OLD ID look like you need some Recursive Query, but *but the register is the same in all times* is contradicting this. Can you add some  example data and expected result?

Comment: In this case, I would need to count how many times the current ID is linked to the old ID, from the same company xpt0 for example
In this case, in 202201, the COUNT() response would be 1, in 202202 it would be 2, in 202203, there would be 2 responses, one with COUNT() = 3 and another with COUNT() = 0, since it has multiples records by company.

Comment: @Dullandal - add your sample data to your post, not as comments